# Is $x<y$ only meaningful if $x$ and $y$ are elements of the same set?

Tags: inequality, logic, relations, formal-languages

$x<y$ means that $x$ is less than $y$, but is it only meaningful/valid if $x$ and $y$ are elements of the same set?

$x<y$ iff $(x,y)\in<$ right?

$(x,y)\in<$ tells that the ordered pair $(x,y)$ is an element of the relation $<$, but what does this ACTUALLY mean?

For example if I have $xRy$, then the meaning of this depends on the definition of the $R$ relation, for example it could mean $x$ is equal to $y$, or $x + 69 = y$. $R$ could very well be defined with $x$ and $y$ being elements of different sets.

Does the same apply for the $<$ symbol?

Comment: Answer: yes, we start with a set $S$, and then order $S$ by defining $x\prec y$ for $x,y\in S$. For example, for $S=\Bbb N^n$ we define a monomial order, e.g., for monomials $x^a=x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ with $a=(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)\in \Bbb N^n$.

Comment: The symbol $<$ or more generally other related symbols like $\prec$ and $\preceq$ and so on are the typical choices for the symbol used for an *order* relation.  What that order relation *means* is contextual, but it will typically have all of the desired properties of what an order relation should have... transitivity, anti-symmetry, (*irreflexivity if strict order, reflexivity if nonstrict*).

Comment: @JMoravitz ok so if its used for order relations, then the elements need to be in the same set right? You cant have a partial order R on A x B, i think

Comment: There can be many possible orders defined for a set.  For instance, words could be arranged in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) (*dictionary order*) so you might say "*apple < banana.*"  There also exist other ways of ordering things... for instance with words you could arrange them in [colexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Colexicographic_order) instead, and you might have some words who are "bigger" than others according to the one where that is different according to the other.

Comment: It's also possible to have a set without a meaningful $<$ operator.  The complex numbers, for example.

Comment: "*then the elements need to be in the same set right?*"  If desired, you could talk about $R'$ over $(A\cup B)\times (A\cup B)$ instead... but typically yes, we only discuss orders over a specific individual set... You could extend definitions and create new definitions however you want, but it is not typically done here.

Comment: Are you getting confused between the underlying set $S$ that $x$ and $y$ are elements of and the relation $R$, which can be considered a subset of $S\times S$?